# Having trouble with input validation/ excluding the highest value/lowest value

Tags: python, validation

I am very, very, VERY new to programming. So far I am really enjoying this class. However lately the programming challenges have been a bit confusing and daunting. The most current challenge I'm on has me scratching my head as I can find no help in my book nor online. In a nutshell I need to create a program that takes the score of five judges in a range of 0-10, exclude the highest and lowest scores given and then calculate the average of the remaining three scores. While I understand how to validate user input for a single value and compute the average, I have no idea how to validate user input for all 5 inputs without doing anything too tedious, and exclude the highest score and lowest score that the user inputs. I have some idea of what I need to do. Take the user input as a float, then transfer it to a function that takes the highest and lowest scores then send it to another function that will compute the average. If anyone could help me with this I'll be really grateful. Below is what I've worked out so far. Thank you in advance.

```
def getJudgeData():
badEntry = True

while (badEntry) :
        judge1 = float (input("Please enter the first judge's score : "))
        if (judge1 < 0 or judge1 > 10) :
            print ("The score must be greater than 0 and less than or equal to 10!")

        else:
            badEntry = False

    while (badEntry) :
        judge2 = float (input("Please enter the second judge's score : "))
        if (judge2 < 0 or judge2 > 10) :
            print ("The score must be greater than 0 and less than or equal to 10!")

        else:
            badEntry = False
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please format your code such that it's a bit more understandable.  To help you get going, you could get the input from the user as a space-delimited set of floats, and then split the result and then find the max/min and check for inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will ask to input a score 5 times, that is why the loop in a range of 5. It will throw a value error if the user's input is not an integer. If you want float, you can change that to a float. If the user input is more than 10, it will prompt the user to inout numbers in the correct range. Then the calculate_average function returns the average rounded to two decimal places, you can change that if needed more or less decimal places.

I was not sure what you meant by subtracting max and min values, so I removed then from the scores. But if I misunderstood, just leave them in there, and then calculate average as normal.

```
scores = []

def getJudgeData():
    for i in range(5):
        try:
            judge_score = int(input("Please enter the first judge's score : "))
            if (judge_score in range(11)):
                scores.append(judge_score)
            else:
                print('Enter a score from 1 to 10')
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter a valid number")

def calculate_average():
    max_value = max(scores)
    min_value = min(scores)
    scores.remove(max_value)
    scores.remove(min_value)
    average = sum(scores)/len(scores)
    return round(average, 2)



getJudgeData()
print(calculate_average())
```

Comment: Sorry if there was confusion! Pretty much I would have to subtract the highest scorew and the lowest score, which would leave me with three scores to use for the average, but thank you for your answer!

Comment: Oh great, because that is what the code above does anyway. I understood you correctly.